# Why the order of listed files in a directory change between Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu-14.04

I have noticed that the order in which Python 3.4 lists files in a directory varies depending on which OS an script is executed. I have a script that list files in a directory using the 'os' package. The order of the list varies depending if I run the script in Windows 10 or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. For Windows 10 the order seems to be the creation date of the files, but I do not know on which basis Ubuntu lists files. Any idea on why this happens and how to avoid it?

My script does this:

```
import os
my_path = 'my/directory/'
files = os.listdir(my_path)
```

Windows 10 result:

```
['my_file_2014', 'my_file_2015', 'my_file_2016']
```

Ubuntu 14.04 result:

```
['my_file_2014', 'my_file_2016', 'my_file_2015']
```

Comment: If you want a specific sorting then sort the list accordingly. I would never rely on the os giving me a specific order.

Comment: The order is not part of the interface contract. If you rely on any particular ordering, you are programming against an implementation detail, not a contract. Don't do that, regardless of programming language.

Comment: The list order on Windows is dependent on the filesystem. The[`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567047) system call builds an [`IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL` : `IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548658) I/O request packet, which is handled by the filesystem device stack, including filter drivers. NTFS directories store files sorted by name in an `$INDEX_ALLOCATION` B-tree attribute named `$I30`.  You can actually use this attribute explicitly when listing an NTFS directory, e.g. `os.listdir('C:\\:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION')`.

Comment: @eryksun: Someone can flag this comment as *"not constructive"*, but I always find myself thankful for your down-level insight, how things operate underneath the documented API contract. And how it can be used upstream. Thank you.

Comment: @IInspectable, I wanted to clarify that, for the common case of NTFS on Windows, the listing is probably sorted by filename, not by creation date, but that this depends on the filesystem. Probably the part about the `$I30` name of the `$INDEX_ALLOCATION` attribute, and its usage, could be seen as not constructive. Windows devs may also dislike discussing system calls instead of the high-level `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` API. We're supposed to pretend that the NT executive is a magic black box.

Comment: @eryksun: In case this didn't come across as intended, I am genuinely thankful for the information you provide. It is insanely helpful to understand, why things are the way they are, even if it isn't contractual. P.S.: I was referring to my comment as not being constructive.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and discussion. It is indeed very informative and constructive.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from `os.listdir` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html):

> The list is in arbitrary order, and does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

Comment: What is __arbitrary__ though? Is this somehow related to hashing?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis probably more related to what the OS is providing (including whether the file system is case-sensitive, etc.; Python just doesn't reorder it.